# Cross origin issue in salesforce response(Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-communities

I tried to get records from salesforce from external local files using JS.
I can see a response in network tab.
i received an error message in console:

> "XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

**MYCODE:**

```
$.post("https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token",
{
    grant_type:"password",
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    headers : {Accept : "application/json","Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"},
    client_id:"CLIENTID",
    client_secret:"CLIENTSECRET",
    username: "uname",
    password: "password"
},
function(data,status){
    //my_function(data);
    console.log(data);
});
function my_function(data){
    alert(data);
}
```

Any help and suggestions.

Comment: That should have to be enable at server side and for cross domain data access either use `jQuery.getJSON()` or  `jQuery.ajax()`.

Comment: your server must allow your origin

Comment: If you are using windows, you can test : 
Run these following commands in command promp  [Windows]: 

`cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application`

`> chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `crossOrigin: true` in your option

```js
$.post("https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token",
{
    grant_type:"password",
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    crossOrigin : true,   /// Add this option 
    headers : {Accept : "application/json","Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"},
    client_id:"CLIENTID",
    client_secret:"CLIENTSECRET",
    username: "uname",
    password: "password"
},
function(data,status){
    //my_function(data);
    console.log(data);
});
function my_function(data){
    alert(data);
}
```

Comment: won't help in this case.

Comment: Yeah, it depends if server not blocking CORS.

Comment: @Jai,@ricky SO need to whitelist the local in salesforce end side?